# How can I make an outlet controlled by switch always hot?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I currently have a receptacle controlled by a switch that I want to make constant hot. There are other receptacles in line as well, that are constantly hot. I opened the receptacle and am lost (not much electrical knowledge/experience). Here a few pictures to show what is going on in the box. Any help is appreciated. [image][image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the receptacle box please?

Comment: Easiest is to open the switch box and connect the two wires with wire nuts.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Props for not disconnecting everything and THEN asking for help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the better picture here

[image: outlet]

There's 3 areas in the picture

- **The Wire Nut** - You have two black and a white. Whenever you see something like that it typically means the white is what's running to your switch. That means the other black wires are your incoming and outgoing hot
- **The black wire on the outlet** - This is likely tied to the same cable as the white wire we just discussed, meaning this is your switched hot
- **The other white wires** - These are your neutrals. It's not clear why you would have 3, however.

First off, let's get this basic outlet out of there. Do yourself a huge favor and go buy a new one. What you want is a "preferred" or "commercial grade" outlet ([example](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Commercial-Grade-Duplex-Outlet-White-R62-CBR15-00W/202066707)) that has side plates. Expect to pay like $2-3 for this (you only need the one). While you're there, pick up some yellow wire nuts. It's not a bad idea to also have a contactless power tester and an outlet tester (buy the better one that also tests GFCIs). Now, let's rewire.

1. Take the wire nut apart and put one of your shiny new yellow wire nuts on the white wire, mark it with a black marker (just draw a band on the wire so it's obvious it's not a neutral), and shove it to the back of the box. Now, attach the two black wires to the brass screws on the left side (as you're looking at the back of the outlet)
2. Take the lone black wire from the outlet and stick a wire nut on it as well. Push it to the back of the box.
3. Attach the remaining whites to the other side (silver). These "side-stab" connectors support up to 4 wires, just make sure you get the screws tight

Obviously, remove and re-attach the ground wire, but that's straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Think about just removing the switch and connecting the wires there, then get a solid cover plate for the switch box. Then,if you ever change your mind, it's a simple procedure to add it back.

Now, let's fix your outlet. With the power off, remove the three white wires from the outlet. For the backstabs, which are notorious for failure, grasp the wire and twist the outlet back and forth, pulling on the wire or use a small screwdriver and insert it in the small slot by each wire. Pigtail the three along with an addition 8" piece of white #14 AWG wire together and hook the extra piece to the silver terminal on the outlet. Remove the black wire from the backstab and hook it around the brass screw of the outlet.

In the future, If you have trouble with any of your other outlets of switches, check first for backstabs. you probably have them throughout your house.

Comment: Jack help me understand what I'm looking at in his pics... I'm usually able to dissect it but having trouble on this one.  First... I only see 7 wires.. where is the other hot? 
 Second, the 3 neutral wires attached to the receptacle... is the receptacle basically being used as a junction for the neutrals? And third... the two blacks and one white bundled in the bottom corner... is that part of the switch loop wiring? I figure the white could be carrying power to the switch, then the black connected to the receptacle is bringing the power back in (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) so, if that is the case, pigtailing the neutrals and putting the black on the screw terminal isn't going to eliminate the switch.     Edit... I overlooked where you said to remove the switch and connect the wires there.. that'd work.

Comment: @clwhoops44  I was thinking there were three black wires under the wire nut. Yes, the outlet is a junction for the neutrals.  Correcting the outlet won't eliminate the switch but the first part of my answer says to remove switch and connect those wires together